# Vuetify Search Textfield in APpbar with faded background and expanding on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

Is it possible in vuetify to add a faded textfield on the appbar which has a faded background and expands on click.

This is an example I have found on  material ui react:

[image]

So far I tried this, but it does not work at all (seems odd)

```
    <v-app-bar :clipped-left="clipped" fixed app class="app-bar-gradient" dark>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
          <v-text-field
            outlined
            label="Prepend inner"
            prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
          ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<template>
<v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <div>
          <v-app-bar>
            <v-toolbar-title class="my-5"></v-toolbar-title>

            <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <template v-slot:extension>
              <v-container>
                <v-row justify="end">
                  <v-col cols="3">
                    <v-text-field
                      name="name"
                      label=""
                      id="id"
                      outlined
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="3">
                    <v-text-field
                      name="name"
                      label=""
                      id="id"
                      outlined
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-container>
            </template>
          </v-app-bar>
        </div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
<style scoped>
.my-5 {
  margin-top: 3em;
}
</style>
```